# Apache 2 on Debian does not recognize .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, debian

Apache 2.2.22 on Debian 7.8 wheezy ignores any .htaccess file.

Part of `apache2.conf`:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In the Apache logs, there's nothing about this problem.

Edit: Working now, I had to change `AllowOverride None` in `<VirtualHost>` to `AllowOverride All` in an included config file

Comment: What are the logs saying ?

Comment: There's nothing about this problem in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you set your AllowOverride in apache2.conf?
AllowOverride is about filepermissions within a specified directory.
Therefor must you change your apache2.conf like this example:

```
<Directory /var/www>
  AllowOverride FileInfo
  ...
</Directory>
```

This is a good thread with more answers:
[How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)

This is the base documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#allowoverride
This for the Directory - tag:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#directory

You can use this also in VirtualHosts.

Edit: Here is an example from one of my virtualhosts:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/Assignments/LoekBergman

<Directory /var/www/Assignments/LoekBergman>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

This works for me.

Comment: I added this to my apache2.conf:
`<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>`
There's no error on restart now, but Apache still ignores .htaccess files.