# htaccess old weblink removing in new website

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My website www.xyz.co.uk. this website in some old link
www.abc.co.uk/xxx i need to user click on any old link then redirect
www.xyz.co.uk page. i try htaccess rule write but not working.

```
# Redirect to xyz.co.uk

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.co.uk [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.co.uk [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# Redirect to xyz.co.uk end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If not using the new domain, then redirect to it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.xyz.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.xyz.co.uk/
```

In the first example, make sure that [`AllowOverride` is set to `All`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) in your Apache configuration.

Comment: Please check your Apache logs. And are you sure the file is named `.htaccess`?