# Failed to add AllowOverrideAll

Tags: apache, clean-urls

I read this article [How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)

I open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
The following code can't find in apache2.conf
So I add the code below by myself.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I open my website, It appear error below.

I add it by myself but my website is down after running apache restart.

```
Internal Server Errror
The server encountered an internal error or misconiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, [no address given]  and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have cause the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: 1) Where in the conf file did you put that?  2) What errors are in the server error log?  3) Have you tried rolling back your change?