# .htaccess for apache 2.2 doesn't work on apache 2.4 vagrant development box

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

The .htaccess file below works fine for various hosted websites, all on apache 2.2, but the test environment and new websites on cloud servers are running on apache 2.4.

The problem is that access to a php file no longer works unless the full filename including .php is added e.g. `www.example.com/about.php` rather than `www.example.com/about`

Any help with the below much appreciated - ideally with a .htaccess that works with both 2.2 and 2.4 apache.

```
Options -Indexes +multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
#ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

# Add www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove .php
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
#RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

---edit---

Below is the apache 2.4 000-default.conf which is used for the VirtualHost

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /vagrant/www/fixdocroot.php

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.dev
   ServerAlias *.dev
   UseCanonicalName Off

   VirtualDocumentRoot "/vagrant/www/%-2+/public_html"

   <Directory /vagrant/www>
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---further edit ---
Apache error log is as follows:

```
[Mon Jan 11 09:26:35.751982 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1812] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 11 09:44:22.816423 2016] [:error] [pid 1892] [client 192.168.33.1:49762] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://speechlink-primary.dev/infant/assessment/start/15
[client 192.168.33.1:49804] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /vagrant/www/domainname/public_html/page-name (None could be negotiated).
```

Comment: may be .htaccess is disabled, check apache config

Comment: Sorry, no it is enabled but thanks!

Comment: Is every statement in your .htaccess ignored, or only some? (for example, does your 404 page works?) Also, is there an error in the apache error log?

Comment: .htaccess appears to be running, the 404 redirect works, the issue appears to be between apache 2.2 and 2.4 handling of the .php rewrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the .htaccess file seems to be the problem:

```
Options -Indexes +multiviews
```

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews):

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

I believe this is interfering with the RewriteRules - in my testing on an Apache 2.4 vagrant box, removing the `+multiviews` from that line seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Great - that cracked it!  Must go back through the docs to see why it was enabled in the first place

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things that can wrong when upgrading from apache 2.2 to 2.4

### Forgetting to enable modules

Sometimes, you can forget to enable the used modules on your new server, this is solved easily by running the apache command `a2enmod <module>`, you are using the module `rewrite` in you .htaccess and this can be activated by `a2enmod rewrite`.

### The configuration parameters you have used are renamed

In apache 2.4, there are some changes in the names of configuration parameters.

According to the [apache update notes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html), the following things are changed:

**`AllowOverride` now defaults to `None`.**

See [@Gal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695731/1542723) for more information about this change.

### PhP may not be installed/enabled at the new server

While I doubt this may be the case, I included it, since this may be a problem for other people.

Check if php is properly installed by making a phpinfo() file, this file contains `<?PHP phpinfo()` and should be giving a proper php info out when run.

Php can be activated on apache with: `a2enmod php5` or `a2enmod php7`

### RewriteRule logging

If the rewrite rules keep failing, a quick test may be enabling the [rewrite rule logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), these can be enabled using the default apache "LogLevel", to prevent making our whole apache emit debug messages, while still getting debug messages from the rewrite modules, you need to prefix the latter using its name. For example:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

This will turn on the rewrite level debug messages to trace3, you can go up to lvl `trace8`.

The debug messages of the rewrite module can be read as follows:

`[rewrite:trace2][rid#7f9c446360a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /` - This means that the rewrite engine has started for a url

`[rewrite:trace3][rid#7f9c446360a0/initial] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri '/'` - This means that a `RewriteRule` has worked

`[rewrite:trace4][rid#7f9c446360a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='^/?projects/old-projects/' => not-matched` - This means that a `RewriteCond` hasn't matched.

`[rewrite:trace4][rid#7f9c446360a0/initial] RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='^/?' => matched` - This means that a `RewriteCond` has matched.

`[rewrite:trace2][rid#7f9c446360a0/initial] rewrite '/' -> '/index.html'` - A RewriteRule has internally/externally redirected you to another page

The best way to read the debug log files is by using a text editor that doesn't wrap the lines, for example `less -R` on linux or Notepad on Windows.

Comment: Just went through to double check, and rewrite was already enabled and is working fine, as is php, as is access to the files and rewrites.  The problem is simply the failure to correctly load the php file if just the main name without the extension e.g. `http://www.example.com/test` should load `test.php`

Comment: @ferrybig If that doesn't work, nothing will haha :)

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the edit. will  check and come back

Answer (score 3):

I was looking into you problem because I had the same issue on my server.

I found a solution that works. From the Apache Docs, [when upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html):

> Errors serving requests:
>
> .htaccess files aren't being processed - Check for an appropriate AllowOverride directive; the default changed to None in 2.4.

It means that the default value of [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#allowoverride) has been changed from `All` To `None`

> Default: AllowOverride None (2.3.9 and later), AllowOverride All (2.3.8 and earlier)

So, to fix this issue you will need to change your `httpd.conf` file (or `apache2.conf`), by adding `AllowOverride All` to your `Directory` block. It wont change any behavior on 2.2 and will fix you issue on 2.4.

You can see more information about how to change your `Directory` block and add the `AllowOverride All` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) nice little thread.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Hi Gal - not ignoring you but need to try this when I get into work on Monday

Comment: Sure. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Hi Gal, sorry to say the config already had  your suggestion. I have published the actual apache .conf in case you have other ideas

Comment: I think this is still the problem. You directory tag is: `<Directory /vagrant/www>` should be `<Directory "/vagrant/www/domainname/public_html">`

Comment: VirtualDocumentRoot should take care of that. If I add each domain's actual document root `/vagrant/www/eachdomain.com/publichtml` then the rewrites all still work except the filename to filename.php