# How to make password prompt for folder in apache2

Tags: linux, apache, passwords

I have installed apache2 in my server(**subDomain.myserver.com**) and i placed more folders in /var/www path. I want to do that when the user access **subDomain.myserver.com/privateFolder** then it should ask password prompt, if the password is valid then show the contents inside the private folder.

Note : I am using linux ubuntu for my server.

How to achieve this?

I tried based on answer :

```
sudo htpasswd -c /home/user/.htpasswd somename
```

and then 
`vi .htaccess` and added lines like below,

```
AuthName "Secure folder"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

and then i moved that .htaccess file into /var/www/protectedContentsHere/.htaccess

But still i can access that all folders inside /protectedContentsHere without prompt box.

where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a .htpasswd file by logging into your webserver using SSH

```
htpasswd -c /somefolderthatisntinapublicwebdirectory/.htpasswd a-user-name
```

Or generate a file online here [htpasswd generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) and upload it through ftp.

Do not put it in a directory (like /var/www), there might be a risk that a user can download the file if you do this.

Create a new file called ".htaccess" and add/upload it to /var/www/privateFolder:

```
AuthName "Secure folder"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /somefolderthatisntinapublicwebdirectory/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Comment: where is that .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry, meant create a new file called .htaccess.

Comment: Add AllowOverride all in your apache config See the following thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22526144/733232