# CodeIgniter - 404 error after HTTPS configured

Tags: codeigniter, https

Helloooo,

I put HTTPS with letsencrypt and it works perfectly. The first page of my website is showing but after I click on a menu item, I got a 404 error.. I look into my controllers and everything is in.

Do you know any solution to this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure you have linked it well?
We need more information of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the AllowOverride directive in your apache configuration.

Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

[Set Allow Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)