# angular ui.router html5mode unable to reload in apache

Tags: .htaccess, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to remove '#' from urls.

Using link with ui-sref or href attributes navigation works properly, but accessing directly to the same url, or refreshing page or pressing enter into url bar of the browser i get 404 not found error.

I enabled html5 mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Added base tag in head before any inclusion:

```
<base href="/folder/" />
```

Here is .htaccess file content (copied from [angular-ui faq](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ /folder/index.html [L]
```

Seems to be a problem related to .htaccess file.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've to:

1. enable AllowOverride in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf ([enable AllowOverride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all))
2. enable mod_rewrite, from terminal `a2enmod rewrite`
3. restart apache from terminal `service apache2 restart`