# How to remove .php extension from live website url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, svn

I referred [alexcican website](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/) and put the code in my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works in my `localhost`, but doesn't work in the`svn link` or `live website`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apache server? Check if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Comment: Check in your apache config whether you have ` AllowOverride None` changed too `AllowOverride All` for your directory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Comment: It's already done. Still not working :( sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: yes. It's working in localhost, But still not in the staging link.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you have created any folder on you live website for your code, than try using below line

RewriteBase /yourFolderName/

keep above code just below RewriteEngine On

Comment: But let me ask a doubt. My localhost also have folders same as in the live site. And then how could it be the problem?

Comment: try keeping RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```