# Why does renameing .htaccess file allow for drupal 7 install on remote server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I'm installing drupal 7 on a remote server. After running tar -xvzf on the install file and moving all the files to a folder just under the public_html folder I enter the site url in to a browser. The result is a 500 server error.  If I then rename the .htaccess file to hide.htaccess.hide the install process will begin. I've experimented w/ the line:

```
RewriteBase /drupal
```

with various paths/folders that make sense but always still a 500 error.

Questions:

1. What is the .htaccess file doing to prevent the install?
2. What is the issues if any of doing the rename?

Answer (score 0):

By default apache allow to override limited settings throught .htaccess file, the .htaccess file provided by drupal overrides more items than allowed to you need to enable to allow override all setting in your vhost config file like...

```
AllowOverride All
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Please refer to following links more details

[How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)

https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to answer what exactly .htaccess is doing/not-doing and why is it a problem on a remote server but not on a local.

Comment: Compare vhost and apache conf settings. I'm sure there something in conf is the cause.