# Redirect Page Url to homepage `.htaccess`

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm noob when it comes to `.htaccess` tricks.

However, I have a **page** http://example.com/register and when a user enters this `URL`, I want this page to redirect directly to **Homepage** or let's say any other page.

I've inserted following `code` inside `.htaccess`, but it's not working.

```
 #Redirect to Homepage   
Redirect 301 /register http://www.example.com/
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache server setting.

Is AllowOverride setted on your root directory.

For example:

`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

See [How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)

Comment: I'm not using Linux server right now. So you mean my code is correct ?

Comment: I have tried in my ubuntu apache22 server, it works.