# Laravel 5.3 route not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed fresh copy of laravel 5.3.

I have the following code in my `route/web.php`.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

when i hit `localhost/project/public` in the browser i can see laravel welcome page.

But when i hit `localhost/project/public/welcome` then `404 Not Found` comes up where i should get the same laravel welcome page.

Am i forgetting something ?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled so you can use .htaccess?

Comment: Please check what happens when you hit localhost/project/public/index.php/welcome

Comment: @VaheGalstyan its working with `localhost/project/public/index.php/welcome`...
Why is that and how can i fix that.

Comment: You should check apache configuration, enable mod_rewrite, after that for best practice please create virtual host, here is a link http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost and everything should work correctly. Reason is your apache configurations maybe mod_rewrite is disabled and .htaccess file dosent work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is case insensitive, so if you created the project with one of these will not find the path.

Answer (score 2):

Has your route file been cached? See what happens when you run:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I was having some trouble with this myself, so for anyone having trouble with getting a Laravel route to work:

1. Make sure your route is defined the correct way by running `php artisan route:list` Your route should show up, along with the method. (get, post, ...)
2. [Enable mod_rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-enabling-mod_rewrite) from the Apache settings so Laravel can map /uri to whatever you like.
3. Modify the .htaccess or [Apache settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) to allow url overrides: [`AllowOverride All`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) If you are working on something like `localhost/~username/yourproject`, also check the `username.conf` file in /private/etc/apache2.

I'm not an expert in Apache settings, so feel free to correct or elaborate where needed.

Answer (score 0):

goto htaccess in your laravel folder
after    ( RewriteEngine On  ) add this

```
RewriteBase  /yourlaravel project name/public
```

example: 
 RewriteBase  /laravel/public