# Allow access to a specified folder .htaccess 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I tried to allow access to a directory by using the `.htaccess` file.
This is my `.htaccess`:

```
<Directory Bilder_Team>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

The directory is "Bilder_Team". If I open the link to this directory, it shows me

> 500 Internal Server Error

How can I fix this?

Comment: check the error_log of your apache server, it shows the actual reason of the error, you can copy it here

Comment: Directory directive is not allowed in htaccess context.

Answer (score 2):

Use this [htaccessCheck](http://www.htaccesscheck.com/) for future checks or problems. Your problem as you could see, once checked, is that you are not allowed tags such as `<Directory>` in `.htaccess` files.

Instead put the `.htaccess` directly into the `Build_Team` directory and leave off the surrounding tags.

Possibly, a bigger problem is the use of `AllowOverride None`, which **disables the use of .htaccess files** and, obviously, has no part of any .htaccess file. `AllowOverride` directive can only be part of the main config file!

As shown the snippet is correct *iff* put in the `httpd.conf` file (*name could vary*). Which actually, if possible, is the better way to do it.

For more information about security concerns, you could refer to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all/18742887#18742887).

Hope this helps!