# how to set right RewriteRule for epmty query

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*) data.php?chn=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have 2 php files.

**index.php** and **data.php**

I to want call **index.php** when the request is for **domain.com/** and **data.php** when the request is for **domain.com/(anything)** .

Comment: where do you host?  do they allow .htaccess overrides?

Comment: web apache2 sir

Comment: for clarification, what is the name of the company that you host with?  or if you are hosting yourself, can you verify that you have allow override all on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Comment: yes all work fine just want call index.php when query is empty (domain.com/) else call data.php (domain.com/?query)

Comment: oooh.  i wouldn't make htaccess do that.  see solution for index.php below

Answer (score 0):

To reroute from index.php...

```
if (!empty($_GET['chn'])) {
  require('data.php');
  exit();
}
```

data.php will already have $_GET['chn'] available to it.

or if you aren't queuing off a get var then you can check the REQUEST_URI and do the same thing:

```
if (@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/')) {
  require('data.php');
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^/(\d+)*$ ./data.php?chn=$1
```

Try this.

**Note:** When using .htaccess in your desired case, placing `/` after the domain name will trigger the second RewriteRule case, meaning user will try to open literally `domain.com/data.php?chn=`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regex pattern from **(.*)** to **(.+)** to avoid rewriting your homepage otherwise the request for **/** will also be rewritten to **data.php** :

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/data\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) data.php?chn=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

its work ! thank you all using  this code :

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ data.php?chn=$1 [L,QSA]
```