# How to change WordPress site URL

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress install on an AWS EC2 instance (LAMP).

I have changed the DNS from godaddy via Route53 and set up an A record and CNAME for the EIP.

I changed the site and home URL in the WordPress admin (from the EIP to http://swsportpsychology.co.uk) and the site wont load. (server not found).

I have changed the site and home URL in both WP-config and functions.php to no avail.

I have also changed the site and home URL in phpMyAdmin (wp_options). For some reason I can load the blog page of the website but the home page doesn't loads. (The site is currently located at /var/www/html)

This is the home IP: http://52.210.185.14

This the blog IP: http://52.210.185.14/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You seem to have a DNS issue; with `traceroute` I get `unknown host swsportpsychology.co.uk` Be sure DNS is set up correctly. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

2) Once the site is up, use this script to change all URLs in the database, i.e. in images and links in post/page content, and in wp_options (theme options, widgets, etc). There are many more instances of URLs in WordPress other than the site address and URL. Upload this via FTP and run: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ And check all theme files for hardcoded URLs of that IP.

3) In order to be sure permalinks will work, be do you have an .htaccess file in root that is 644 writable? And did you allow `allowoverride` in `apache2.conf`? [How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)