# Symfony 3 https rewriteRule

Tags: symfony, https, url-rewriting

I'm using symfony and I just set up ssl on my server. Then when I send a request https de my app the symfony's htacces doesn't seem to rewrite the url, instead I see the tree-folder.
Does someone knows which rule to set up?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your SSL VirtualHost configuration is missing `AllowOverride` directive (and PHP stack as well).

See: [How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)