# phpmyadmin giving 500 error after update the apache2.conf

Tags: php, linux

I am using Linux mint. I am working in a Wordpress, It was not possible navigate a page. I got a answer from a source to change the apache2.conf file like bellow

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But for me the phpmyadmin is not working after this change. For that problem i go for this

Adding

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
```

in the phpmyadmin.conf file. But still it is working. Is there are anything i have left.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's in /var/log/apache2/error.log?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Comment: @ino I have followed those instructions before.

Comment: These are the errors 

[Wed Dec 06 17:16:06.564005 2017] [core:notice] [pid 19855] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 06 18:04:34.965555 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19855] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Dec 06 18:04:35.158577 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20775] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 06 18:04:35.158740 2017] [core:notice] [pid 20775] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'