# Laravel 5.5 all routes except home result in 404 not found

Tags: laravel-5

Just trying out laravel 5.5 which I installed in cpanel. Only the root route is working:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('public/content/home-content');
});
```

Even this isn't working

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('public/content/about-content');
});
```

It also work:

```
www.mydomain/index.php/about
```

How can I solve this error

Comment: if the route works with index.php in url, you should try to enable rewrite_module in apache modules

Comment: in which route file your routes are written ?

Comment: @karthik, any solution to enable rewrite_module in laravel project

Comment: if rewrite_module is not enabled then also home should not work right? @karthik Nk

Comment: What happens if you go to `index.php/about`?

Comment: @niraj, it works, not show 404

Comment: That means it's definitely a rewrite issue. What OS and server software are you using?

Comment: @FaridulKhan You just need to enable that module from your cpanel

Comment: @PrateikDarji he said root is working

Comment: @karthik, before i didn,t enable module in cpanel. if i change it, any effect on other project which develop in codeigniter?

Comment: @FaridulKhan not sure about that. But if ur previous projects are working fine without .htaccess(rewrite), i think there wont be an issue. Or you have another option. Try running the laravel project without rewrite(that's how it is based on ur comments).

Comment: Thanks, @karthik, it is working now

Comment: This answer will help you [This answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all/22526144#22526144)