# Can not use PHP code in html file

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-7

After i updated from PHP 5x to PHP 7, i have some issues, I have used all way below in my .htaccess

```
1/AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
2/AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

And many different ways i've done in my .htaccess file but it still not working, i also tried to show PHP error, but it not show anything.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

All the html tag display as well, but it cannot read PHP code

Comment: Try setting `AllowOverride` to `All` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) and see if that works.

Comment: @Mike, thank you, i'll contact to my sysadmin to try that

Comment: If you're into contacting your sysadmin about this, you might as well just tell them to put the `AddType` and `AddHandler` right in your Apache conf file. Even create a test file that they can use to test to make sure it's working correctly.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you either add an answer here to explain how you fixed the problem or delete the question, because without an answer it is not helpful to future users of the site.