# How to change the apache httpd port for serving files

Tags: linux, apache, centos7, httpd.conf

Currently,  I have the following IP address with this port:

```
http://292.168.14.23/
http://292.168.14.23:80/
```

The above addresses behave identically and have been used for serving the [local
UCSC Genome Browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/help/mirror.html).

What I want to do now is to set a new IP address, say `http://292.168.14.23:8080/` -- namely using `8080` as a port instead of the default `80` --  that I can use to serve basic files in Apache. So when I do this:

```
http://292.168.14.23:8080/my_spec_dir/myfile.txt
```

I can navigate and download the files from the browser.
How can I do that?

Following [this instruction](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-change-apache-ftp-and-ssh-default-port-to-a-custom-port-part-1/), I tried changing this file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
with these lines:

```
Listen 8080
ServerName 292.168.14.23:8080
```

Although this address work: `http://292.168.14.23:8080`,  I still cannot get access to the file: `http://292.168.14.23:8080/my_spec_dir/myfile.txt`

Note that `my_spec_dir` is stored under `/web/html`, and it is configured in `httpd.conf` this way:

```
#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/web/html">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Comment: This could be useful, please have a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: @Deepanshu  I don't have GUI, all using command line.

Comment: Along with modifications in **httpd.conf**, make one more entry in **http-ssl.conf** `Listen 8082(any free port)
<VirtualHost _default_:8082>
ServerName localhost:8082`....save and restart apache....and check if it works.

Comment: Please, allow us to Google that for you: [apache add ip and change port](https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+add+ip+and+change+port).

Comment: Your action should be enough. What error do you see when trying to access http://292.168.14.23:8080/my_spec_dir/myfile.txt ?
Is it possible that Selinux block it.(you can verify it by setting Selinux to permissive mode: # setenforce 0)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have added configuration override through htaccess files?

```
<Directory /path/to/public/website/>
   AllowOverride All <--
   ...
</Directory>
```

> [How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)
>
> Htaccess manual:
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change global document root

```
Listen 8080
ServerName 292.168.14.23
DocumentRoot "/web/html/my_spec_dir"
```

Or if you want a virtualhost.

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost 292.168.14.23:8080 >
    DocumentRoot "/web/html/my_spec_dir"
    ServerName 292.168.14.23

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```