# How to configure .htaccess for subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a WordPress site hosted on AWS and I am having a hard time to configure `mod_rewrite` to work correctly.

#### Folder structure

```
/root
  |_ staging/
  |_ live/
```

The `.htaccess` is the WordPress default

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

### Main Problem

I can access `/staging/index.php/api` which I used to access it without subdirectories like this `---.com/api`.

When I try `/staging/api` it shows `File not found`.

I tried to change the `.htaccess` to different thing but none of them was successful.

There are no `.htaccess` file in the root directory.

Some help would be appreciated =)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /staging
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Note: The **AllowOverride** should be set to **All** in server configuration.
You can find the reference from here.
[How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)

Comment: I did try that in the `/staging/.htaccess` but didn't work

Comment: Can you share you .htaccess code how you modified? Or else try with update this line
`RewriteBase /staging`
to
`RewriteBase /staging/`

Comment: ```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```
that is the new `.htaccess` file
I have tried both `/staging` and `/staging/`

Comment: Strange thing. I am using the same and working for me. Have you checked this in your server configuration if everything is good?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Also can you please share your server configuration?

Comment: I changed the AllowOverride in the main apache configurations and it worked. Thanks very much