# Magento 2.1 memory issue

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

In Magento 2.1.0 I do the Readiness Check when installing new extensions. The readiness check tells me that my memory_limit is set to 800M, but the server is set to 2000M and I have changed the .htaccess file in shop root so it it set to 2000M two places in that file as well.

Where else can it be set?

Comment: So you modified correct php.ini and restarted Apache?

Comment: I am on a shared host so I cannot restart Apache.

Answer (score 1):

in .htaccess Two memory_limit will be available

1. One for PHP 5
2. One for PHP 7

Please change it in mod_php7 and try seeing phpinfo() on your browser.

If it is still displayed as 800M Then your are editing in a wrong file.
Change it in your last loaded ini file.

Comment: I am editing in the .htaccess in the root directory. I am on a shared host but I should be able to change it. But it still says 800M

Comment: For the server to accept the changes in .htaccess files, your apache config needs to be set with AllowOverrides permission
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18742887/12029873

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you are trying Magento installation in shared or dedicated hosting environment?

If shared then you have limitation on changing the PHP behaviour using the ini or .htaccess files.

If dedicated then try to use phpinfo(); function and see from which path the php.ini is loading. Most likely editing ini in the loaded path and restarting apache should work.

If it is still problem, kindly share technology stack with the screenshot.

Good Luck!