# How could I navigate directly from the toolbar menu without manually editing it

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-9

I am having trouble when navigating through some pages because when clicking on a menu item it goes to

```
http://localhost/drupal/admin/structure
```

and its giving me this error

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

but if I manually added index.php after the site name

```
http://localhost/drupal/index.php/admin/structure
```

It does work. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Try http://localhost/drupal/web/admin/structure

Comment: no not working @Gabri

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have enabled apache server rewrite engine (or alternative if you have some other web server). To use aliases it has to be working.
If it is enabled check if you have .htaccess file in webroot dir. If you copied your files from somewhere it could happen that hidden files (those starting with dot) are not copied.

Comment: Yes, I had enables mod_rewrite and it does exist in the Loaded Modules in info.php. and the .htaccess is in my webroot directory and I have tried to put some dummy text inside it and it results in an error so I think it is being processed. But the issue still exists

Comment: Do you have "AllowOverride All" in your virtual host setup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all