# React router 404 Error On (Litespeed Webserver)

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router, litespeed

I am building movie app, initialize with create-react-app. I am using `react-router@5`. I get 404 Error  when route url on production (on Litespeed webserver) but it's work on local machine.

Example Url :

```
www.example.com/tv/detail/131959
```

I am research on issue and found `.htaccess` file configuration, but configuration for apache or tomcat and I use litespeed web server.

AppRouter.js

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter >
      <Navbar />
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/:type/detail/:id" component={DetailPage} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
};
```

For inspect visit github repo: https://github.com/egecanyldrm/movie_app

**.htaccess config**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: LiteSpeed is essentially the same as Apache (some "_minor_" differences). What is your `.htaccess` config?

Comment: Hey @MrWhite added above my .htaccess config

Comment: And where are the `.htaccess` and `index.html` files located? Is the 404 error a LiteSpeed response or from your app?

Comment: .htaccess and index.html located same root . Yeah error is litespeed response visit my web site [movie-app](https://movie-app.egecanyildirim.com/)

Comment: The homepage works OK (`server: LiteSpeed`), but it seems inner pages are not - but these are coming from `server: AmazonS3` / `x-cache: Error from Cloudfront`? Is the `.htaccess` file doing anything at all? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled in the server config? Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: I think `.htaccess` file not work. ı don't know what is overrides enabled server config.  Yes ı have access server config

Comment: "what is overrides enabled server config." - `.htaccess` overrides need to be enabled in the server config (by default `.htaccess` files are not processed). In the relevant `<Directory>` container that relates to the document root directory you would need to set something like `AllowOverride All`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess is correct,
you should edit script and css src in HTML file, for this follow these steps

1. go to your project files directory it seems like that `/var/www/html/`
2. run this command `nano index.html`
3. edit script path from this `./static/js/main.123.js`
   to `/static/js/main.123.js`
4. and style sheet path from `./static/css/main.12345.css` to `/static/css/main.12345.css`
5. then save file by press `^s` then close it by `^x`

إن شاء الله it will work and you can change script path py open file and change it without `nano` if it is possible for you.

Comment: How does this relate to the question?!

Answer (score -1):

Update your .htaccess with following script

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

I'm using LiteSpeed and it works

Comment: This is the same as the code already presented in the question?! (If you read the comments below the question it would seem the `.htaccess` file is not being processed at all?)