# Permalinks are not working in wp installation, that runs on ip address in subfolder

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have just installed wp 6.0 on my home server (no domain, only ip address with a port specified, and also in subfolder), and i have access to this site (main page and admin panel are working fine). Also all the site is working if i set permalinks settings like:

```
http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:8091/subfolder/?p=123
```

But pages except main page and admin panel do not work (it shows 404 error) if i set this setting to:

```
http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:8091/subfolder/sample-post/
```

In general settings i have:

```
WordPress Address (URL): http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:8091/subfolder
Site Address (URL): http://xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:8091/subfolder
```

And, finally, my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What i have to change to fix the 404 error issue? I want to use the nice format of permalinks, not the ?p=123

Comment: Did you enable .htaccess files in your Apache configuration?  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: This was the problem, thanks! Now i have "allowoverride all" setting in apache2 conf - and is working fine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set AllowOverride all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all)