# How to redirect sub directories to parent directory in the backend using apache2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, directory, alias, subdirectory

I built a react app for a recipe website. But now, after I uploaded it to my server which is already hosting multiple other folders, when I refresh one of the subpages it shows my 404 page.
I am trying to figure out a rule allowing me to rewrite everything from
`mysite.xyz/folder/subfolder/` to `mysite.xyz/folder/` in the backend so it doesn't show the url change for the user and react router gets the right url. While at the same time allowing access to the existing static files stored in `folder/static/`.
How may I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it.
Just create a `.htaccess` file in your folder with the following inside.

```bash
# Direct non-existing paths to index.html
FallbackResource /folder/index.html
```

Also you might have to enable [`.htaccess` overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all) in your main apache configuration file (`000-default.conf` for me which was located  in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`)