# The requested URL xxx was not found on this server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using wordpress and when I switch the permalinks to "post name", it doesn't load the page rather showing 404 not found. The requested URL xxx was not found on this server. It's on Amazon AWS EC2

I already tried changing .htaccess and I confirmed rewrite_mode is enabled. Even I changed the AllowOverride to All.

Here is the .htaccess content,

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea, what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you restart apache after you made the change for AllowOverride? You can test your .htaccess by putting random text at the top and if you get 500 internal error then it's reading your .htaccess otherwise it's not.

Comment: I am assuming you get the 404 error with wordpress? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362629/url-rewriting-not-working-with-wordpress-unless-using-r/25385434#25385434) might help you.

Comment: Yes, I have already restarted the Apache Server after made changes to the AllowOverride to All. I just found that .htaccess is not being read. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Panama Jack said above, I found that my .htaccess file wasn't being read. I just followed the answer in this thread and my problem solved.

[.htaccess file not being read ("Options -Indexes" in .htaccess file not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769880/htaccess-file-not-being-read-options-indexes-in-htaccess-file-not-working)

Thank you for your help Panama Jack :)

Regards
Sudharsan,
OnDeOs