# Force redirect to login page in PHP

Tags: php

I'm setting a web application for an E-commerce project which has an administrator panel. How do I force and auto redirect to login.php instead of index.php?

For instance, if I did follow this path http://localhost/project/admin (this will load index.php).

However, the login process runs successfully and session opened when I try to open `login.php` manually via http://localhost/project/admin/login.php

Folder Structure:

- Both index.php and login.php are in admin folder
- connection.php, admin-header, admin-footer are in include folder
  Path http://localhost/project/admin

> using XAMPP Panel  v3.2 on windows 10

I've tried the below:

> login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include '../include/connection.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "select * from admin where admin_email = '$email' AND admin_password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $adminSet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($adminSet['admin_id']) {
            $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $adminSet['admin_id'];
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        else {
            $error = "You are not authenticated.";
        }
    }
?>
```

> admin-header.php // which included on index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])) {
        header("location:login.php");
    }
?>
```

> index.php

```
<?php include '../include/admin-header.php'?>
```

Comment: note: [should-i-call-exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553698/php-should-i-call-exit-after-calling-location-header)

Answer (score 5):

#### Option1 (DirectoryIndex)

In your admin directory, create an `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
DirectoryIndex login.php
```

#### Option2 (RewriteRule)

In your admin directory, create an `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php login.php [L]
```

I tested option 2 and it works fine if you requested `/admin` or `/admin/` or `/admin/index.php` , you will get redirected to `login.php` in the 3 cases

#### Option 3 (HTTP redirect)

Make your `index.php` like this:

```
<?php
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
```

I don't prefer option 3 to save the extra HTTP request.

[Make sure your Apache is allowing .htaccess files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769880/htaccess-file-not-being-read-options-indexes-in-htaccess-file-not-working)

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache) also.